# Как поставить раскрывающийся блок div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="sidebar_map_block" id="map"></div>
<button onclick="maxMap()">увеличить</button>
```

поставил в footer заработал

```
<script>
var mapWrap = document.getElementById("map");

function maxMap() {
  mapWrap.style.height = '500px';
  // св-во style предоставляет доступ к свойствам стиля элемента
}
</script>
```

Сейчас появилась другая проблема, яндекс карты не раскрываются по идеи там element style стоит на 100% ширину diva
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

вот код самого яндекса

```
<div id="[[+mapId]]" [[+style]]></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(function(){
        [[+mapId]] = new ymaps.Map("[[+mapId]]", {
            center: [[+map.center]],
            zoom: [[+map.zoom]]
        });
        [[+mapId]].setType("[[+map.type]]");
        var [[+mapId]]Controls = "[[+controls]]".split(',');
        for(var i = 0; i < [[+mapId]]Controls.length; i++){
            [[+mapId]].controls.add([[+mapId]]Controls[i]);
        }
        [[+placemarks]]
        [[+polylines]]
        [[+polygons]]
        [[+routes]]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: У вас скрипт находится в head-ере, должен находиться либо ниже блока `<div class="sidebar_map_block" id="map"></div>`, либо используйте функцию `window.onload`, потому что на момент исполнения строчки `var mapWrap = document.getElementById("map");` блока такого еще не существует

Answer (score 1):

> поставил в head
>   var mapWrap = document.getElementById("map");

На момент исполнения скрипта элемента ещё нет, поэтому `document.getElementById("map")` вернёт null. По хорошему, надо бы дождаться загрузки документа, а потом искать элемент. Другой рабочий вариант - поместить этот скрипт после элемента (или вообще в конец body). А я бы искал элемент непосредственно при клике - не вижу смысла держать лишнюю переменную.

Comment: а как быть с элементом который внутри дива? при клике на кнопку увеличивается высота дива, но не элемента у которого стоит 100%

Comment: @reddyk, ну так его и увеличивать. Или ему height 100% прописать.

Comment: у sidebar_map_block стоит 280px, а у yandex map height:100% и так стоит, если через этот скрипт увеличивать до 500px, то карта всеравно остается с 280px

Comment: @reddyk, Потому что 100% должно быть внутри.

Comment: не понял? так карта внутри этого дива и принимает 100% значение этого же и дива

Comment: @reddyk, Давай код на jsfiddle.

Comment: <div id="map" [[+style]]></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(function(){
        [[+mapId]] = new ymaps.Map("[[+mapId]]", {
            center: [[+map.center]],
            zoom: [[+map.zoom]]
        });
        [[+mapId]].setType("[[+map.type]]");
        var [[+mapId]]Controls = "[[+controls]]".split(',');
        for(var i = 0; i < [[+mapId]]Controls.length; i++){
            [[+mapId]].controls.add([[+mapId]]Controls[i]);
        }
        [[+placemarks]]
        [[+polylines]]
        [[+polygons]]
        [[+routes]]
    });
</script>

Comment: на jsfiddle врядли получится, это плагин для modx revo

Comment: @reddyk, Я в этом разбираться не буду. Либо код куда-то, где его можно править (в виде js), либо пытайся сам применить описанную идею.

Answer (score 0):

Какой то шаблонизатор используете?

```
var mapWrap = document.getElementById(/* тут id блока */);

function maxMap() {
  mapWrap.style.height = '500px';
  // св-во style предоставляет доступ к свойствам стиля элемента
}
```

Теперь повесьте на клик функцию maxMap

На счет второго вопроса: у ya.map должен быть метод resize, нужно использовать его, потому что автоматически height не изменяется. ( не сильно знаком с api, поэтому точное название метода не скажу )

Comment: это на modx revo, всмысле <div id="maxMap"></div> ?

Comment: Не совсем, допустим у вас есть кнопка `button`, тогда что бы на нее повесить обработчик, нужно написать `<button onclick="maxMap">`

Comment: поставил но вроде не работает, изменил сам вопрос

Comment: @reddyk Забыл, необходимо скобочки поставить, что бы функция выполнилась `<button onclick="maxMap()">увеличить</button>`

Comment: всеравно не хочет, id блока map, а класс другой, может function какой то из них ставить?

Comment: @reddyk [вот демо](http://jsbin.com/seqifevica), там использовал тот же код. Просто поместите код не в `head`, а перед закрывающим тегом `body`.

Comment: да все отлично работает)